# Is Diffie Hellman key exchange based on one-way function or trapdoor function?

Tags: diffie-hellman, one-way-function, trapdoor

I have a question for my information security lab, which I am not able to find online.
As the title says, is Diffie Hellman key exchange based on a one-way or a trapdoor function?

In case of RSA I would say it is based on a trapdoor function, since it is hard to factorize the modulo, if you don't know p and q.

Is Diffie Hellman also based on a trapdoor function, since it is hard to reverse the discrete logarithm, if you don't know the secret key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the mathematical problem that is used for Diffie-Hellman is the [Diffie-Hellman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_problem) or DHP which is different from the trapdoor function that is behind RSA.

One way functions are for instance cryptographically secure hash functions.

Comment: Let me know if you need a mnemonic for that :P

Comment: Oh okey, sounds good thanks :) Whats your mnemonic? :P